# How to declare this R CSV data as numerical?

Tags: csv, r

I added spaces around my fields in CSV file in Vim csv.vim plugin. 
Now, I am having difficulties in declaring the column classes as numerical (`num` etc). 
Having negative values there also cause problems in the following columns
The data can have empty fields. 
Data `data.csv`

```
Test, test2, test3
    , 1    , 1
10.8, -1   , 1
1.1 , 2    , 2
```

Code

```
library('methods')
DF <- read.csv("/home/masi/Data/data.csv", header = T, sep = ",", colClasses=c('num','num'))

DF
```

Output

```
Error in methods::as(data[[i]], colClasses[i]) : 
  no method or default for coercing “character” to “num”
Calls: read.csv -> read.table -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

- Casting to numerical fails  when doing `colClasses=c('num','num')`.
- Output in Column 3 is considered as `NA` because of one minus mark (`-1`) in the second column.

R: 3.3.3

Comment: I don't know anything about R, but is it possible that the importer is complaining about the "character" (non-numeric) header line?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think it is not the case because I have `header = T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `num` is not a valid *atomic vector class* in `R`:

> Possible values are NA (the default, when type.convert is used),
>   "NULL" (when the column is skipped), **one of the atomic vector classes
>   (logical, integer, numeric, complex, character, raw)**, or "factor",
>   "Date" or "POSIXct". Otherwise there needs to be an as method (from
>   package methods) for conversion from "character" to the specified
>   formal class.

Your code should work if you replace it by `numeric`:

```
> DF <- read.csv("data.csv", header = T, sep = ",", colClasses=c('num','num'))Error in methods::as(data[[i]], colClasses[i]) : 
  no method or default for coercing “character” to “num”
```

whereas

```
> DF <- read.csv("data.csv", header = T, sep = ",", colClasses=c('numeric','numeric'))
> 
> DF
  Test test2 test3
1   NA     1     1
2 10.8    -1     1
3  1.1     2     2
>
```

Comment: My mistake. It is strange that the shorthand of `TRUE` as `T` is accepted, but not of other types etc `num` for `numeric`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [readr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=readr) package with argument `trim_ws=TRUE` in `read_delim()`:

```
R> readr::read_delim("data.csv", delim=",", col_types="dii", trim_ws=TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
   Test test2 test3
  <dbl> <int> <int>
1    NA     1     1
2  10.8    -1     1
3   1.1     2     2
```